# RewriteRule issue with Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm launching a new site with Codeigniter and in my .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|codes|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I need to add rules in here to permanently move some pages from the current site to the new site, i.e.

```
/london
```

to

```
newsite.com/events/london
```

301 redirects always result in a query string and RewriteRule never works for me. I think the current one is screwing it up, because it works if I remove it. How can this be achieved? I have about 40 redirects to write.

Thanks

Comment: use the application/config/routes.php file. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Hmm, that's not what routing is for though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this by putting trailing slashes on my rewrites:

```
Redirect 301 /london http://newsite.com/events/london/?
```

I still get the ? at the end but that's where it stops, so will do for now.